# Group by find summary measure, non NA value, and specific value using summarise in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this sample dataset (`df`)

```
structure(list(from = c("(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", 
"(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452", "(122) 212-3452"), to = c("(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", "(700) 890-6542", 
"(700) 890-6542"), extension = c("9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", "9205 - Raw IRS Calls", 
"9205 - Raw IRS Calls"), forwarded_to = c(NA, "(323) 457-2039", 
"(310) 598-1753", "(818) 900-0706", "(818) 539-7811", "(213) 344-4965", 
"(213) 458-7662", "(818) 208-3012", "(818) 293-0175", "(818) 284-4238", 
"(818) 206-9506", "(310) 299-7340", "(310) 405-0875", "(213) 260-9113", 
"(213) 805-5208", "(818) 887-3058", "(424) 271-2141", "(213) 218-6579", 
"(818) 638-9466", "(213) 784-7164", "(323) 457-2038", "(213) 805-6959", 
"(228) 285-7898", "(213) 341-1055", "(213) 568-0979", "(213) 344-4905", 
"(818) 459-3811", NA, "(323) 457-2039", "(310) 598-1753", "(818) 900-0706", 
"(818) 539-7811", "(213) 344-4965", "(213) 458-7662", "(818) 208-3012", 
"(818) 293-0175", "(818) 284-4238", "(818) 206-9506", "(310) 299-7340", 
"(310) 405-0875", "(213) 260-9113", "(213) 805-5208", "(818) 887-3058", 
"(424) 271-2141", "(213) 218-6579", "(818) 638-9466", "(213) 784-7164", 
"(323) 457-2038", "(213) 805-6959", "(228) 285-7898", "(213) 341-1055", 
"(213) 568-0979", "(213) 344-4905", "(818) 459-3811"), date = c("Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", "Mon 12/31/2018", 
"Mon 12/31/2018"), time = structure(c(55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 
55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 
55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55440, 55500, 55500, 
55500, 55500, 55500, 55500, 55500, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 
55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 
55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55320, 55380, 55380, 
55380, 55380, 55380, 55380, 55380), class = c("hms", "difftime"
), units = "secs"), action = c("Phone Call", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "Phone Call", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe", 
"FindMe", "FindMe", "FindMe"), action_result = c("Accepted", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "IP Phone Offline", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "Stopped", 
"Stopped", "IP Phone Offline", "Stopped", "Stopped", "Call connected", 
"Stopped", "Accepted", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"IP Phone Offline", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", "No Answer", 
"No Answer", "Stopped", "Stopped", "IP Phone Offline", "Call connected", 
"Stopped", "Stopped", "Stopped"), result_description = c("The call connected to and was accepted by this number.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"This DigitalLine was either not plugged in or did not have an internet connection.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
NA, NA, "This DigitalLine was either not plugged in or did not have an internet connection.", 
NA, NA, "The call connected to and was accepted by this number.", 
NA, "The call connected to and was accepted by this number.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"This DigitalLine was either not plugged in or did not have an internet connection.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
"The phone number you dialed was not answered.", "The phone number you dialed was not answered.", 
NA, NA, "This DigitalLine was either not plugged in or did not have an internet connection.", 
"The call connected to and was accepted by this number.", NA, 
NA, NA), duration = structure(c(297, 52, 52, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 0, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 9, 9, 0, 9, 
9, 236, 9, 71, 52, 52, 52, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 0, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 7, 7, 0, 13, 7, 7, 7), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), ID = c(19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), CallConnected = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), who_answered = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "(213) 344-4905", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "(213) 341-1055", "NA", 
"NA", "NA")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-54L))
```

This shows that call data of phone numbers that made the call and received the call. **The full dataset has a lot more pairs of numbers, but I've only posted one pair for brevity**

I'd like to find the number of `TRUE` in `CallConnected` within each pair of numbers, the first phone number inside `who_answered`, and the duration value that corresponds to `Call Connected`. I've thought of using `group_by` and `summarise` but I can't figure out a way.

The desired output would look like:

```
from          | to           | CallConnected | WhoAnswered  | Duration
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(122) 212-3452|(700) 890-6542| 2             |(213) 344-4905| 00:03:56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can count number of `CallConnected` by taking `sum` of `TRUE` values, find the first value of non-"NA" `who_answered` column and the first `TRUE` value from `duration`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarise(count_call = sum(CallConnected), 
            who_answered = who_answered[which.max(who_answered != "NA")],
            Duration = duration[which.max(CallConnected)])


#  from           to             count_call who_answered   Duration
#  <chr>          <chr>               <int> <chr>          <time>  
#1 (122) 212-3452 (700) 890-6542          2 (213) 344-4905 03'56"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you were pretty close to a solution. Here's my version:

```
df %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  filter(CallConnected) %>%
  summarise(CallConnected = n(),
            WhoAnswered = first(who_answered),
            Duration = first(duration))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
output <- df %>%
  filter(CallConnected == TRUE) %>%
  group_by(from, to) %>%
  summarise(duration = sum(duration), firstWhoAnswered = first(who_answered), CallConnected = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this-

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dt)[CallConnected==TRUE,.(from,to,CallConnected,who_answered,duration)][,head(.SD,1),by=.(from,to,CallConnected)]

             from             to CallConnected   who_answered duration
1: (122) 212-3452 (700) 890-6542          TRUE (213) 344-4905 00:03:56
```